# Sharepoint Crawler - Multiple host names

Tags: search, crawling

i have a number of host names in the crawler.
I would like to know which host names are consuming the most time / resources.
Does sharepoint perform crawling sequentially for each host name? 
How can I know how much time each hostname took to crawl?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Sharepoint 2010. Apologies for not including this beforehand

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an option per host name, but there is per content source. You may want to consider creating a content source per site, or group the sites into a few content sources.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Creating a content source per site makes sense. but in the current setup there is a single content source. with multiple start addresses. If I navigate to crawler log, there is a Host Name in the menu.

Comment: Yes, the crawler log will break down the search by host name, but this doesn't include the stat you want to see, it's just the success/error status. Drilling down further by clicking on the host name gives you more details on the status, but no timing.